# pyqtgraph in pydev disappear after a second

Tags: python, pydev, pyqtgraph

I started to play with pyqtgraph. I am using PyDev as IDE.
When I code a simple plot it shows and disappear straight away. The same does not happen in IPython, where it show and stays.

For example:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
'''shows graph but disappear. Doesn't happen in ipython'''  
dataX = [1,5,2,5,3,5,4,5,5,5,6,5,7,5,8,5,9,5,10]
pg.plot(dataX)
```

will not work from PyDev but show correctly in IPython.
I tried to add `pg.show()` but is does not change. I know there is some similar problem with matplotlib if it's interactive but I can't find it in pg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running ipython you run the script in interactive mode. Your script above will finish and cleanup once it has reached the bottom. Try adding the following to the bottom of your script to start the qt event loop (copied from the pyqtgraph examples):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```